# I have a parent child list ,that list i want to convert in parent child json which i mentioned below

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this json format after convert the list

```
[
    {
        "Id": 13,
        "createdDate": "2019-12-25T15:07:43.68",
        "ModifiedDate": "2019-12-25T15:07:43.68",
        "CreatedBy": "",
        "ModifiedBy": "",
        "Parent": "root",
        "ParentId": 0,
        "Label": "abc",
        "Filename": "root_abc_13",
        "ImagePath": "/Images/Gallery/root/root_abc_13.png",
        "ThumbPath": "/Images/Gallery/thumbs/root/root_abc_13.png",
        "children": [
            {
                "Id": 15,
                "createdDate": "2019-12-25T15:08:33.303",
                "ModifiedDate": "2019-12-25T15:08:33.303",
                "CreatedBy": "",
                "ModifiedBy": "",
                "Parent": "root_abc_13",
                "ParentId": 13,
                "Label": "bb",
                "Filename": "root_abc_13_bb_15",
                "ImagePath": "/Images/Gallery/root_abc_13/root_abc_13_bb_15.png",
                "ThumbPath": "/Images/Gallery/thumbs/root_abc_13/root_abc_13_bb_15.png",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 14,
        "createdDate": "2019-12-25T15:08:12.837",
        "ModifiedDate": "2019-12-25T15:08:12.837",
        "CreatedBy": "",
        "ModifiedBy": "",
        "Parent": "root",
        "ParentId": 0,
        "Label": "bb",
        "Filename": "root_bb_14",
        "ImagePath": "/Images/Gallery/root/root_bb_14.png",
        "ThumbPath": "/Images/Gallery/thumbs/root/root_bb_14.png",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

I tried to code below to get the list and convert to parent child list 
 This is a class

```
public class Tree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? createdDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }


    public string Parent { get; set; } // Activities

    public int? ParentId { get; set; } // parentid
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }


    public string ThumbPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("children", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IList<Tree> Child { get; set; } = new List<Tree>();

}
```

Logic

```
public IEnumerable<Tree> TreeFlatToHierarchy(List<Tree> list)
        {
            // hashtable lookup that allows us to grab references to containers based on id
            var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Tree>();
            // actual nested collection to return
            var nested = new List<Tree>();

            foreach (Tree item in list)
            {
                if (lookup.ContainsKey((int)item.ParentId))
                {
                    // add to the parent's child list 
                    lookup[(int)item.ParentId].Child.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    // no parent added yet (or this is the first time)
                    nested.Add(item);
                }
                lookup.Add(item.Id, item);
            }

            return nested;
        }
```

after getting the result convert to json  to SerializeObject or DeserializeObject

```
    var tree = TreeFlatToHierarchy(tree);
    var jsonSerializeObject= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree );
    var jsonDeserializeObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonSerializeObject);
```

My code logic and other all is going fine but i need different json format.below is have a json format please advice me how i get this format

```
[
    {
        "Id": 13,
        "createdDate": "2019-12-25T15:07:43.68",
        "ModifiedDate": "2019-12-25T15:07:43.68",
        "CreatedBy": "",
        "ModifiedBy": "",
        "Parent": "root",
        "ParentId": 0,
        "Label": "abc",
        "Filename": "root_abc_13",
        "ImagePath": "/Images/Gallery/root/root_abc_13.png",
        "ThumbPath": "/Images/Gallery/thumbs/root/root_abc_13.png",
        "w2ui": {
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 15,
                    "createdDate": "2019-12-25T15:08:33.303",
                    "ModifiedDate": "2019-12-25T15:08:33.303",
                    "CreatedBy": "",
                    "ModifiedBy": "",
                    "Parent": "root_abc_13",
                    "ParentId": 13,
                    "Label": "bb",
                    "Filename": "root_abc_13_bb_15",
                    "ImagePath": "/Images/Gallery/root_abc_13/root_abc_13_bb_15.png",
                    "ThumbPath": "/Images/Gallery/thumbs/root_abc_13/root_abc_13_bb_15.png",
                    "w2ui": {
                        "children": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": 14,
        "createdDate": "2019-12-25T15:08:12.837",
        "ModifiedDate": "2019-12-25T15:08:12.837",
        "CreatedBy": "",
        "ModifiedBy": "",
        "Parent": "root",
        "ParentId": 0,
        "Label": "bb",
        "Filename": "root_bb_14",
        "ImagePath": "/Images/Gallery/root/root_bb_14.png",
        "ThumbPath": "/Images/Gallery/thumbs/root/root_bb_14.png",
        "w2ui": {
            "children": []
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you use the wrong tag?  None of the code shown is C.

Comment: O  My mistake thanks for mention it

Comment: What is wrong with the current format?

Comment: Nothing anything wrong just i need that format which i mentioned above because that json format required in w2ui tree grid view

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-arrange your model as below.  whenever you have doubts you can user JSON to CSharp [converters](http://json2csharp.com) to get an idea about how to structure your model.

```
 public class Tree
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? createdDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }


    public string Parent { get; set; } // Activities

    public int? ParentId { get; set; } // parentid
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }


    public string ThumbPath { get; set; }

    public Collections w2ui {get; set;}
}

public class Collections
{
    [JsonProperty("children", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IList<Tree> Child { get; set; } = new List<Tree>();
 }
```

**Edit**
To add the items to list you can modify your code as below

```
    foreach (Tree item in list)
        {
            if (lookup.ContainsKey((int)item.ParentId))
            {
   var collection = lookup[(int)item.ParentId].w2ui?? new Collections();
   collection.child.Add(item);
                // add to the parent's child list 
                lookup[(int)item.ParentId].w2ui = collection;
            }
            else
            {
                // no parent added yet (or this is the first time)
                nested.Add(item);
            }
            lookup.Add(item.Id, item);
        }
```

Comment: Using this model how to identify the parent child list ..logic already mention above in code where i identify parent child tree list. when i use above model i got error in 
     lookup[(int)item.ParentId].Child.Add(item);

Comment: updated answer with code changes for your query. Please check if this works for you.

Comment: I try but return nested json name is same can you please update ho to change the name.Updated the code with json.

Comment: Sorry you mean you need to change the JSON node name from w2ui to Children?

Comment: Please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204927/room-for-rajesh-g-and-faraz-saleem).

Comment: No,I want to change Children to w2ui, now you code return node name children i want like the  "w2ui": {
      "children": [
        {}]}

Comment: Also in future you can always convert your JSON to C# or C# to JSON using online converter and verify your approach. Can you please accept my answer and up vote?

Comment: Sure i appreciate your help to solve the problem.thanks